# Houston, we have a problem with [anatomy]

Tags: discussion, tagging

The tag [anatomy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anatomy) refers to astronomy (which already has the tag [astronomy](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astronomy)), rather than the discipline of medicine or biology.

Unfortunately, I can't blank out the description (the site doesn't allow me to do so), so someone needs to replace it with accurate content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed, and well spotted! The solution was to *correct* the tag excerpt, not blank it.